# Get total from CTE query

Tags: sql-server, string, common-table-expression

I have the following query:

```
WITH Years AS
( 
    SELECT 2004 AS [Year]
    UNION
    SELECT 2005
    UNION
    SELECT 2006
    UNION
    SELECT 2007
    UNION
    SELECT 2008
) 
SELECT *
FROM Years
```

Result:

```
Years >> Alias Column
2005
2006
2007
2008
```

That will return the years. Based on those years, I need to get the total # of orders from `AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderHeader`

How should I code it? Union? I should not modify my 1st code, but need to add something right after it, so when I select the codes, F5 (execute), it should show me the totals. Also, at the end, there should be a string 'Total Orders:' added with the sum of all the years from the CTE.

Here is the result:

```
Year            TotalOrders
----------------------------
2005             1379
2006             3692
2007            12443
2008            13951
Total Orders:   31465
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should get the count where Year of Orderdate in AdventureWorks2012 is equal to your year in CTE, then group it by Year - this is the CTE "temp" from my query below. Then sum the count and add the 'Total Orders:' by Union.

```
temp AS 
(
    SELECT      CAST([Year] AS Varchar(15)) AS [Year],
                COUNT(*) AS [TotalOrders]
    FROM        Years
    INNER JOIN  AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
    ON          DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) = Year
    GROUP BY    [Year]
)

SELECT  [Year],
        [TotalOrders] 
FROM    temp 
UNION
SELECT  'Total Orders: ',
        SUM([TotalOrders]) 
FROM temp
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? Where is the temp coming from? Selecting both code and executing is not working since the Year is from the CTE table.

Comment: @Bill temp CTE is referencing from your Years CTE, since you mentioned that it should not be touched. By adding a comma after your CTE - With Years AS (...), temp will be considered as a CTE as well.